# mamba install of FASTBOOK leading to provider install issue

Tags: python, ubuntu, deep-learning, libffi, mamba

While trying to run command below

```
mamba install -y fastbook
```

I am receiving the problem/error below

```
Looking for: ['fastbook']

fastai/linux-64          [====================] (00m:00s) Done
fastchan/linux-64        [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/r/noarch            [====================] (00m:00s) Done
fastchan/noarch          [====================] (00m:00s) Done
fastai/noarch            [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/main/noarch         [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/r/linux-64          [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/main/linux-64       [====================] (00m:01s) Done

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.9.5


Encountered problems while solving:
  - package python-3.9.5-h12debd9_4 requires libffi >=3.3,<3.4.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed
```

This is all part of instructions I am following here

https://course.fast.ai/start_aws#step-6-setup-server

Comment: probably need to add the **conda-forge** channel

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
mamba install fastbook -c fastchan
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the fastai channel and it worked:

```
 mamba install -c fastai fastbook
```